# How to direct user back to the app screen from webView by using onBackPressed (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, back-stack, onbackpressed

I've used this but this is not what I want. Since I have only one privacy policy webpage to show there is no use of  canGoBack() and it closes the app on back press. I want to just close the webView.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val webView= findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)

      if (webView.canGoBack()){
          webView.goBack()}
else{
    super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

So if you have any solution in Kotlin please help!!

Comment: Don't create a new variable inside `onBackPressed `, create a top level one & the initialise it in your `onCreate` & then us that variable to check in `onBackPressed`

Comment: Is your WebView in a second Activity or in the Launcher Activity?
If it's in second Activity please the code you are using to start the WebView activity.

Comment: How about hiding and showing your webview. Based on your code snippet, this isn't a fragment or an activity, thus I'd suggest you show and hide your `WebView` to fake the back button pressed behaviour. Let me know if that is enough to solve your problem so that I can provide an answer with code snippets.